# What is meaning of use {} as the criteria for update function

Tags: mongodb

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

Refer to [update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)

I have seen the following usage of {} inside update as a criteria.

```
collection.update({}, {$push : { x : 1}})
```

What is the meaning of {} here? Does it mean no criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `update` specifies criteria used to find documents to be updated. Setting the first argument to `{}`, will match against every document in the collection. By default, only the first match will be updated. To update all matched documents, set `multi` to true.

Comment: Not all documents are affected. If you want to get that results, you have to apply the following statement instead `db.collection.update({}, {$push : { x : 1 }}, false, true)`. Be aware that by default, update() only modifies the first matched object.

Comment: Edit your answer to include that bit of information. It's a weird default.

Answer (score 0):

What maxenglander said is true only if you specify multiple to true (which is 4th argument).

Otherwise only the first document will be updated (in mongo's natural order)